# Hue attribute in seaborn strip plot is not changing the color of the points

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot, hue

I am using seaborn pair plot to plot the data points over top of a boxplot. I want the points in the pair plot to correspond to their categories. I have added an attribute of hue= category, but it is not actually changing the color of the markers or allowing me to create a legend of what each color corresponds to.

My dataset is a large covid 19 dataset that I cannot upload here, but essentially I am plotting a boxplot of the percent of vaccinations per the number of deaths in each region of the world. My current code is as follows:

```
box= sns.boxplot(
    data= covid_by_region,
    y= 'vac_v_death',
    color= 'white'
)

points= sns.stripplot(
    data= covid_by_region,
    y= 'vac_v_death',
    hue= 'region',
    size= 10,
    palette= 'Set2'    
)
```

The resulting graph is:
[Boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0CgH.png)

I do not understand why the hue is not working on the pair plot to set a different color to each region.

Answer (score 3):

You indicated in the question that you are using a pair plot, but the code says `stripplot`. I hope you are asking why the points are not of different color.
The `stripplot` is expecting both X and Y axis data to give the colors that you are expecting. You can give a dummy variable for `x` and that would give the desired result.

A simple code with dummy data to give you an idea of what has to be done...

```
data = {'region': ['A', 'C', 'B', 'D'],
        'dummy':['X', 'X', 'X', 'X'], 
        'vac_v_death': [3, 10, 6, 1]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

box= sns.boxplot(data= df, y= 'vac_v_death', color= 'white')

ax=sns.stripplot(data= df, x='dummy', y= 'vac_v_death', hue= 'region', size= 10, palette= 'Set2')

ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False) #Remove the tick and label for dummy
```

**Output graph**

[image: Colorful Strip plot]

Comment: Note that if you want a custom label for the X-axis and not have the 'X' show up at tick, you can use two lines to replace the suggestion here for `ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)`. In place of that line, instead you can use `ax.set_xlabel("Custom X-axis Label Goes Here")` followed by the line `ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks()[0].set_visible(False)`.